# Installing an EV certificate straight into the cPanel

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I just bought an EV SSL certificate from geotrust and I was wondering if its possible to install it straight from the cPanel (ssl category). The single problem I'm having with that is that its asking me a private key that isn't mentioned in the e-mail where I received the certificate.

I'll appreciate any advices , thank you!

Comment: It's the same private key used to generate the certificate signing request (CSR) that you would've submitted when purchasing the certificate.

Comment: How or where did you generate the CSR certificate in order to get the SSL certificate?